# How to call directive function from controller in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a update model function in my directive which I want to call from controller. How do I access directive function from controller? I am able to call on model change but for that I have to perform click event.

Below is my code:

```html
<div ng-if="((individualDropdown && YesRadio) || FolderDropdown)">
  <searchable-multiselect display-attr="infoMarketCodeWithName" 
    selected-items="formData.market" 
    all-items="allMarkets" 
    add-item="addMarketToList(item,allMarkets)" 
    remove-item="removeMarketFromList(item,allMarkets)" 
    ng-disable="NoRadio || NotSureRadio"
    ng-model="formData.market" name="marketDropdown">
  </searchable-multiselect>
</div>
```

Directive code and the function to call is `updateSelectedItems`

```js
app.directive("searchableMultiselect", ['$timeout', '$filter', function($timeout, $filter) {
        return {
          templateUrl: "Templates/SearchableMultiselect.html",
          require: 'ngModel',
          restrict: "AE",
          scope: {
            displayAttr: "@", //one way binding & only expression
            selectedItems: "=", //two way binding & expects model name
            allItems: "=",
            readOnly: "=",
            addItem: "&",
            removeItem: "&", //method binding               
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(event) {
              event.stopPropagation();
            });
            scope.updateSelectedItems = function(obj) {
              console.log(scope.allMarkets);
              //code goes here
            }
          }
        ])
```

Answer (score 1):

From an AngularJS good practice perspective, you should enforce the separation of concerns principle by not putting such a strong dependency on the controller to know function names in directives and such.

One alternative is to use an event-driven approach, where the directive submits an event, which is captured by the controlled and acted upon, with the cycle being close by updating the model.

```
app.directive("searchableMultiselect", ['$timeout', '$filter', function($timeout, $filter) {
    return {
        templateUrl: "Templates/SearchableMultiselect.html",
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            displayAttr: "@", //one way binding & only expression
            selectedItems: "=", //two way binding & expects model name
            allItems: "=",
            readOnly: "=",
            addItem: "&",
            removeItem: "&", //method binding               
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            });

            scope.updateSelectedItems = function(obj) {
                console.log(scope.allMarkets);
                scope.$emit("updateSelectedItems", scope.allMarkets);
            }
        }
    }   
}])
```

And in the controller:

```
app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on("updateSelectedItems", function (event, allMarkets) {
        // Do stuff with data
        // Update data model bound to directive if necessary
    });
}])
```

Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score -1):

When the directive uses the [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), the `selected-items` attribute is redundant:

```
<div ng-if="((individualDropdown && YesRadio) || FolderDropdown)">
  <searchable-multiselect
    display-attr="infoMarketCodeWithName" 
    ̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶-̶i̶t̶e̶m̶s̶=̶"̶f̶o̶r̶m̶D̶a̶t̶a̶.̶m̶a̶r̶k̶e̶t̶"̶
    ng-model="formData.market"
    all-items="allMarkets" 
    add-item="addMarketToList(item,allMarkets)" 
    remove-item="removeMarketFromList(item,allMarkets)" 
    read-only="NoRadio || NotSureRadio"
    name="marketDropdown">
  </searchable-multiselect>
</div>
```

Use the [`$setViewValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue) method to set the selected value:

```
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        displayAttr: "@", //one way binding & only expression
        ̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶I̶t̶e̶m̶s̶:̶ ̶"̶=̶"̶,̶ ̶/̶/̶t̶w̶o̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶b̶i̶n̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶&̶ ̶e̶x̶p̶e̶c̶t̶s̶ ̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶
        ngModel: "<",
        allItems: "<",
        addItem: "&",
        removeItem: "&", //method binding               
        readOnly: "<",
    },
    ̶l̶i̶n̶k̶:̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶,̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶a̶t̶t̶r̶s̶)̶ ̶{̶
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.bind('click', function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        scope.updateSelectedItems = function(obj) {
          console.log(scope.allMarkets);
          //code goes here
          ngModel.$setViewValue(obj);
        }
    }
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)
- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#overview)